# How to add a "required" checkbox in this code

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I want a checkbox in this code. Only if the checkbox is checked it should be possible to press upload / or to allow a upload.

Could you give me a hint how it's possible to change this?
Actually I can insert a checkbox but it's always uploading if the checkbox is unchecked.

```html
@extends('master/index')
@section('custom')
<!-- Main page -->

<div id="content-wrapper" class="snap-content">
    <!-- Progress bar -->
    <div class="container progress-holder">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="progress-rate">--%</div>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <span class="sr-only">--% Complete</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Drag zone -->
    @if($limitReached == true)
    <div class="container text-center start-zone">
        <p>{{ t('You have reached daily upload limit') }}</p>
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="container text-center start-zone">
        <form id="fileupload" action="{{ route('images.upload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png">
            <input type="file" id="input-browse" class="block-hide" multiple="multiple" name="files">
            <p>{{ t('Drag photos from your computer in here. Select maximum 10 images') }}</p>
            <div class="help-block">{{ t('Maximum file size allowed is') }} {{ maxUploadSize()*1024 < (int)siteSettings('maxImageSize')*(1024) ? maxUploadSize() : (int)siteSettings('maxImageSize') }}MB (o.O)</div>
            <p>{{ t('You can also') }} <a class="browse_files" href="#">{{ t('browse') }}</a> {{ t('for photos to upload') }}.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    @endif

    <div class="uploader block-hide">
        <!-- Preview zone -->
        <div class="container preview-zone">
            <img src="{{ asset('static/img/mask-tran.png') }}"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Thumbnail zone -->
        <div class="container thumbnail-zone">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <ul class="thumbnails-holder nav nav-tabs" id="myTab"></ul>
                </div>

                <div class="actions col-md-3 text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> remove</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-upload"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i> upload</button>
                    <p class="help-block"><span class="readyphoto"></span>/<span class="totalphoto"></span> photos are ready</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Edit zone -->
        <div class="container-fluid tab-content edit-zone-holder"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript using the onchangeevent event to enable/disable button based on checked value

```
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="document.getElementById('uploadButton').disabled = !this.checked;" />

<input type="submit" id="uploadButton" value=" Upload " />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable and enable buttons with jQuery depending on the checkbox selection.

If you have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$("#upload").prop('disabled', true);

$("#checkbox").bind('change', function(){        
        var checked = this.checked;
        if(checked){
            $("#upload").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $("#upload").prop('disabled', true);
        }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkcen0wg/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Add this in your html form.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="writeSomeName" value="value">
```

Then after that write some php code:

```
if ($_POST['writeSomeName'] == 'value')
{
     //Add code for upload file here
}
else
{
  echo "You have not checked the checkbox. Please make it check first"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="yourvalue">
```

add onclick event in your upload button

```
<button type="button" onclick="selected()">upload</button>

<script>
function selected()
{
   if(document.getElementById('chk').checked) {
    document.getElementById("fileupload").submit();
   } else {
    alert('YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work but if the alert message pops up and I click ok the picture is uploading automatically.
Seems like the script is still executing

Comment: means without checking the checkbox it submitting the form??

Comment: Yes if I dont check the checkbox and press my upload button it shows me the else message (alert). After pressing OK on the alert message it submit the form.